# How to build video player like udemy with node.js #nodejs

Tags: node.js, video-player

How to build video player that record the progress of video when user get back. And checked the video that has been completely watch?

Comment: This is far too broad, what have you already tried? Add some details.

Comment: Please have a read on the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It should improve your chances to get an answer and avoid downvotes.